# Count number of rows in DataTable that meet some criteria

Tags: asp.net

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable();

if(field=="TaskId")
{
    string value = ((e.Item as GridFilteringItem)[field] as GridTableCell).Column.CurrentFilterValue
    int VALUE = Int32.Parse(value);           
    int numberOfRecords = dt.Select("TaskId = VALUE").Length;
```

I want to count the number of rows in a `DataTable` that have a `TaskId == value`.

This code is throwing an error saying no column found TaskId[value].

Comment: Perhaps a DataView with a RowFilter
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3060221/695

Comment: row filter also have tried but what actually happening here is instead of VALUE when I mention direct column value 2 or 3 then it is working..but dynamically I want it based on the value being entered in Radgrid ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

```
int numberOfRecords = dt.Select("TaskId = VALUE").Length;
```

WITH

```
int numberOfRecords = dt.Select("TaskId = " + VALUE).Length;
```

you passed VALUE within ("")

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple for loop to iterate each row, looking at the `TaskId` field of each row. If it matches the criteria, increase a counter.

```
string value = ((e.Item as GridFilteringItem)[field] as GridTableCell).Column.CurrentFilterValue

int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(dt.Rows[i]["TaskId"].ToString() == value)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Either that or you could use LINQ as well. The rows variable will hold a collection of DataRows that meet your criteria.

```
var rows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           where row.Field<string>("TaskId") == value
           select row;

int count = rows.Count<DataRow>();
```