# filter crystal report by textBox values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on a crystal report in vb.net  , the report displays the System Users Information(UserName,Position,Salary), i want to filter the report at the run time using the Drop Down List  and text box.
 The drop down list to choose the field which the report will be filtered by it "eg:USerName ", and the text box to set the filter Field value"eg:Eric" .

the problem is that i don't know how to replace the crystal report old data with the new one after filtering

I am new with crystal reports , Please any help would be appreciated ..

this is my code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    GetData()


End Sub


Protected Sub GetData()


    Dim connStr As String = ""
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter

    Try

        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "GetUsersInfo"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ds = New DataSet()

        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(ds)

        Dim rd As New ReportDocument()
        rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Users.rpt"))

        rd.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd

    Catch ex As Exception

        ex.Message.ToString()


    End Try


End Sub

 Protected Sub FilterDdL_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FilterDdL.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim filterField As String
    Dim filterFieldValue As String


    filterField = FilterDdL.SelectedItem.Value

    filterFieldValue = FilterFieldVal.Text


     DataTable1.User_Name = ?filterFieldValue


End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify :  _When you select Eric in dropdown then data should be shown for Eric only,right? and where does `DataTable1` comes from and how it get filled?_

Comment: @Vivek.S Yes , DataTable1  Oh it should be a comment since i was thinking a bout  how  to do  that " filtering  database  and then re assign new data table to crystal report"

Comment: Just show proc `GetUsersInfo`

Comment: @Vivek  the procedure will bring all users info from the DB

Comment: You can do this in two ways that's why I asked to show the create script of that proc, btw does it returns any ID for the username like `userid` or something?

Comment: @Vivek No in this Proc i didn't return the user id because it  will not be displayed in the report

Comment: This may help you to find the solution http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2014/01/02/ado-net-how-to-filter-data-in-a-datatable.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060194/how-to-correctly-filter-a-datatable-datatable-select

Comment: @Vivek.S thanks for your time and helping me .. this is about filtering data table , i need to filter crystal report data

Comment: You can  filter datatable before assigning it to crystal report data source and get values from DB after selecting dropdown